# Campaign Exclusion Report

Tags: reporting, leads, campaign, cross-filter

I am having trouble creating a Campaign with Leads report and could use some help.

I have Salesforce Enterprise edition.

I have a population of 324 leads that are all campaign members of  Campaign A.  188 of those 324 lead are also campaign members of Campaign B. (I have over 110 campaigns running some any of these leads may also be associated with any number of those campaigns)

I am trying to build a report which displays ALL leads that are campaign members of Campaign A **BUT NOT** campaign members of campaign B.

**Another issue - When I use Cross Filters with parent object LEAD and child object CAMPAIGN HISTORY the report display a row for EVERY campaign that a single LEAD record might be associated with which is annoying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Campaign Combiner app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IlDHEA0) on the AppExchange was built for this purpose.